# Написание JPQL запроса

Tags: java, hibernate

Собственно нужно правильно написать запрос
взять из таблицы фамилию ,которая чаше всех встречается за полгода

я делаю что то вроде вот такого но не получается так как не особо знаком с синтаксисом jpql

```
  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT p, COUNT(p.lastName) FROM Purchase p GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY COUNT(p.lastName) DESC")
    List<Purchase> bestBuyer(@Param("from")Timestamp f,@Param("to")Timestamp t);
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что сам запрос у вас выполняется, ошибка возникает скорей всего в момент маппинга на объект  Purchase потому, что в данном объекте нет поля count. В данном случае можно создать отдельный объект и замапить ответ на него.  А вообще нужно видеть что в логах пишется, какое исключение чтоб было больше ясности.

Comment: @Query("SELECT DISTINCT p, COUNT(p.lastName) FROM Purchase p GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY COUNT(p.lastName) DESC")
    List<Purchase> bestBuyer(@Param("from")Timestamp f,@Param("to")Timestamp t);

Comment: сейчас это выглядит так - компилируется нормально ,но не дает нужный результат

Comment: Запрос синтаксически неверный. Как можно в выходной набор помещать таблицу-источник??? Должно быть `SELECT p.id FROM ...`. *взять из таблицы фамилию ,которая чаше всех встречается за полгода* Если задача ИМЕННО ТАКАЯ - с какой целью Вы вообще помещаете ненужное `COUNT(p.lastName)` в выходной набор?

Comment: а как сделат так чтобы не помещать-запрос то я уже составит и он работает ,но вместе с фамилией выдает еще и количество )